# Django Email backend (keeps sending email from incorrect "sender")

Tags: django, email

I have several instances in my project where I attempt to send an email within a Django view.

I want to be able to hardcode the email sender within the view.  When I try to do so, though, it continues to send the emails from the default account specified in my settings file.

Here is an example:

```
        if testform.is_valid():
            beta=testform.save()
            subject="Hi Beta Tester"  
            sender="correct@email.com"

            recipient=[testform.cleaned_data['email']]

            text=loader.get_template('registration/beta_email.txt')
            html=loader.get_template('registration/beta_email.html')

            site_name='mysite'
            d=Context({'site_name':site_name})
            text_content=text.render(d)
            html_content=html.render(d)
                #This sends two mail versions, plain text and html
            msg=EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, sender, recipient)
            msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
            msg.send()

            return HttpResponseRedirect('/splash/')
```

I thought that I could send specify the sender argument explicitly here.  And, yet, when I test it, the email is being sent from the address listed in my settings file, configured as the following:

```
       EMAIL_USE_TLS=True

       EMAIL_HOST='smtp.gmail.com'

       EMAIL_HOST_USER='wrong@email.com'

       EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD='private'

       DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL='wrong@email.com'
```

Do I just have to remove the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL constant to make it work?  I tried doing so and it seems to be working but I'm confused. In the Django documentation, it suggests that setting sender in the view should override the DEFAULT.

Comment: That seems like it should work. What version of Django? Take a look at the source for the trunk version: https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/core/mail/message.py#L198 . Are you absolutely sure `sender` isn't None when you pass it in to `EmailMultiAlternatives`? I'd play around with this in the interactive shell and with pdb.

Comment: Hi Brian, I'm using v1.2.  I think that my issue is becoming clear, if you look at the comment below

Comment: Are you sure its not the smtp server rewriting the from address?  ie: gmail doing to some spam protection.

Comment: Hi John, I'm new to smtp servers, so I'm not aware of how to debug that.  This is pure development environment, so my emails haven't been marked as spam.  Not sure if that matters

Comment: I do know that addThis (the social media sharing webservice) is able to send emails from any gmail account to any other gmail account

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've finally figured out the issue here.  Unfortunately, gmail rewrites the from and the 
envelope on authenticated smtp.

If you want to get around that, you have to use a third party mail server (which doesn't act like such a prissy) and then send mail to gmail users.

Answer (score 2):

For the sender e-mail try putting it in < > and you can add a name:

```
sender = "Formal Name <correct@email.com>"
```

that is exactly the syntax I have in my e-mail sending view and it works.

There really shouldn't be a reason that adding the name to it would change how it's sending, but it may be worth trying and perhaps you want an easily readable name anyway.

Comment: I just tested this out j and I think that it's the solution.  Let me test it out a little bit more.

Comment: Ok something interesting is happening here. My emails all default from the EMAIL_HOST_USER constant.  the real value of that constant is a google apps account (basically, help@mysite.com).   When I try to send mail from brendan@gmail.com, it just reverts back to the EMAIL_HOST_USER value.  HOWEVER, when I send something from another user within the google apps account (i.e. support@mysite.com), it uses support rather than help.  That is funny, I don't know what to do about it.

Comment: effectively, that's fine when I want to send a message to my user from my google apps account.  But it's a problem when I want to have one user send a message to another user via their respective email accounts

Comment: @Brendan that is interesting... So you are trying to send messages from users to users? Are you hosting their e-mail accounts or are they all gmail accounts too?

Comment: Hey J, I am trying to send messages from user to user.  They are all gmail accounts.  I was under the impression that that was possible...as I mentioned above addThis, for one, does it. Anyone can spoof the from field, right?

Comment: Another interesting wrinkle, I took another look at the Django email documentation.  With the send_mail() function, you can add optional auth_user and auth_password arguments (I had just been using "subject", "message", "sender", and "recipient_list").  When I include the auth arguments, I get closer to my goal.  This time, I override EMAIL_HOST_USER and end up sending it from the auth_user.  However, that still requires a password, so it doesn't work as far as sending gmail messages back and fort between users

Comment: @Brendan I think 'spoof' is the right word for it, but gmail is pretty good about picking that up as (potential) spam. _But_ that doesn't mean you shouldn't be able to do it without error. Are you sure your variable for sender are being passed in correctly? "if omitted, the DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL setting is used" [docs](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects)

Comment: I've commented out DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL, so it's now defaulting to EMAIL_HOST_USER. I guess my question is how can I spoof within the Django module?  I also printed out "sender" and it has the expected value.

Comment: well now my website is not sending any e-mails so I can't even test things. Uh... confused. Maybe it's just being slow and I'm going to get flooded in a min

Comment: Hey J, I went on the django mail group and figured it out.  See my answer, I think it could be useful to someone else.  Thanks for all the effort to help me out, it's much appreciated