# SMTPSenderRefused - 553, From address not verified - Django Email Forms

Tags: python, django, email, django-forms

I have a simple Django contact form (user email, message). I had configured a Gmail server and it was working but it always rewrote the from address with the address listed in settings.py as pointed out by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5952416/3136225) as well. So I've configured my settings using a Yahoo Mail server instead.

Here is my **settings.py** file

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myid@yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

Here is my **views.py**

```
def contact(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                'Contact Us',
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', ''),
                ['myid@yahoo.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('thanks')
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
    return render(request, 'hunt/contact.html', {'form': form})
```

Now I'm getting a `SMTPSenderRefused` exception.

Exception value - `(553, 'From address not verified - see http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/mail/original/manage/sendfrom-07.html', 'someone@gmail.com')`

**EDIT** - I tried putting my own id `myid@yahoo.com` in the Email field and it worked. It only seems to be working for my email id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost all public mail servers allow only emails with actual author's email in `From` header. You are trying to send email with "From: some_user@email.com", which is being rejected. Really, it's much like your problem with Google, but Yahoo drops an error instead of silently messing with headers.

I'd put user's email into message body here, and maybe tried to put it into 'Reply-To' [header manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/email/#django.core.mail.EmailMessage).

P.S. It's usually better to use named keyword arguments for every possible function (in your case - `send_mail`). It often help to avoid silly arguments order errors.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing, using the 'Reply-To' Header.